# R - Compute Mismatch By Group

Tags: r, sequence, dplyr, hamming-distance

I was wondering how could I compute **mismatching** cases **by group**.

Let us imagine that this is my data :

```
sek = rbind(c(1, 'a', 'a', 'a'), 
        c(1, 'a', 'a', 'a'), 
        c(2, 'b', 'b', 'b'), 
        c(2, 'c', 'b', 'b'))

colnames(sek) <- c('Group', paste('t', 1:3, sep = ''))
```

The data look like this

```
     Group t1  t2  t3 
[1,] "1"   "a" "a" "a"
[2,] "1"   "a" "a" "a"
[3,] "2"   "b" "b" "b"
[4,] "2"   "c" "b" "b"
```

In order to get something like

```
Group 1 : 0 
Group 2 : 1
```

It would be fancy to use the `stringdist` library to compute this.

Something like

```
seqdistgroupStr = function(x) stringdistmatrix(x, method = 'hamming')

sek %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  seqdistgroupStr()
```

But it is not working.

Any ideas ?

**Quick Update**: 
How would you solve the question of weights? For example, how could I pass an argument - a value (1,2,3, ...) - when setting the **mistmatch** between two characters. Like the **mismatch** between *b and c* cost **2** while the **mismatch** between *a and c* cost **1** and so on.

Comment: so by "mismatch", you mean the number of rows for each group where at least one element is different?

Comment: yes exactly - basically the hamming distance

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your definition of `sek`, the last line should be `c(2, 'c', 'b', 'b'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will give you the number of mismatches by group, where a mismatch is defined as one less than the number of unique values in each column t1, t2, etc. for each level of Group. I think you would need to bring in a string distance measure only if you need more than a binary measure of mismatch, but a binary measure suffices for the example you gave. Also, if all you want is the number of distinct rows in each group, then @Alex's solution is more concise.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

sek %>% as.data.frame %>%
  melt(id.var="Group") %>%
  group_by(Group, variable) %>%
  summarise(mismatch = length(unique(value)) - 1) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(mismatch = sum(mismatch))

  Group mismatch
1     1        0
2     2        1
```

Here's a shorter `dplyr` method to count individual mismatches. It doesn't require reshaping, but it requires other data gymnastics:

```
sek %>% as.data.frame %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(length(unique(.)) - 1)) %>%
  mutate(mismatch = rowSums(.[-1])) %>%
  select(-matches("^t[1-3]$"))
```

Comment: You could use `num_range("t", 1:3)` instead of `matches()`

Answer (score 6):

Here is another `dplyr` solution that does not require any transformation of the data into long/wide forms:

```
library(dplyr)
sek = rbind(c(1, 'a', 'a', 'a'), 
            c(1, 'a', 'a', 'a'), 
            c(2, 'b', 'b', 'b'), 
            c(2, 'c', 'b', 'b')) %>%
    data.frame

colnames(sek) <- c('Group', paste('t', 1:3, sep = ''))

sek %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>%
    distinct(t1, t2, t3) %>%
    summarise(number_of_mismatches = n() - 1)
```

Comment: I see you now use `distinct` ;)

Comment: live and learn! note, I am using it in the way I think it should be sensibly used, not to find distinct cases of the grouping variables ;)

Comment: Nice solution. Avoids reshaping data.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(sek) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Group) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(dist = n_distinct(value)-1)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#  Group dist
#1     1    0
#2     2    1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m <- matrix(apply(sek[,-1], 1, paste, collapse=''))
newdf <- as.data.frame(cbind(sek[,1], m))
names(newdf) <- c('Group', 'value')
newdf %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarize(count = length(unique(value))-1)
#  Group count
#1     1     0
#2     2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Base package:

```
aggregate(cbind(dist = Groups) ~ Groups, 
          data = unique(sek), 
          FUN = function(x){NROW(x)-1})
```

With `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
df <- rbind(c(1, "a", "a", "a"), 
            c(1, "a", "a", "a"), 
            c(2, "b", "b", "b"), 
            c(2, "c", "b", "b"))
df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)[1] <- "Groups"
sqldf("SELECT Groups, COUNT(Groups)-1 AS Dist 
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM df) 
      GROUP BY Groups")
```

Output:

```
  Groups Dist
1      1    0
2      2    1
```